# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error only when upgrading app. Clean install of app works fine. iCloud

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, icloud

I have an existing app in the app store, and I'm adding iCloud. I've followed Apple's guides as well as others and its all working fine. However I've noticed that if I have version 2.0 of my app (the last production version) installed on a device and then I deploy version 3.0 (the one with iCloud) from Xcode to the device, when I run the app I get:

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: com.yourcompany.YourApp has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement
```

However if I delete the original app from the device then deploy 3.0 from Xcode I don't get the error, and iCloud works fine.

What should I do so that users don't have to delete the app prior to upgrading?

I've tried this on multiple devices running iOS 5.0.1 and they all do the identical thing.

Comment: iOS 4.3.5? There is no iCloud in this version

Comment: I feel really dumb for saying that... But I have tried it on multiple devices running 5.0.1 and still have that issue.

Comment: And can you post your com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier value?

Comment: $(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.yourcompany.YourApp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an issue with the entitlements procedure.
Have a look at the following tech note: [Technote 2285](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2285/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011323)

Quote:

> Do not use Xcode to install or run updates to your app for quality
>   assurance testing.
>
> To make the development cycle faster, Xcode only pushes changed files
>   into the apps it runs, and does not delete files from existing
>   app-bundles. This makes builds significantly faster. But it means that
>   running with Xcode on top of an old build can produce a build that
>   erroneously has outdated files that the app will not have when
>   downloaded from the App Store. This can cause problems during testing
>   and mask bugs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this creates a problem if you need to retain data in the app sandbox between tests.  If your app performs special processing on its first launch and saves values to NSUserDefaults (for example), you can't delete the app if you want to see what happens on the second launch.  The warning is definitely true, though; I've seen entirely wrong screens from deleted XIBs come up and render the whole app inoperative.

Comment: In that case I would recommend that you prepopulate the sandbox when your app starts.